# How to left align currency symbols in right aligned DataGridView cells?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that looks like this:

[image]

I want the currency symbols to line up on the left of cells. How can I do this?

I imagine I'd have to rewrite the rendering function.  Is there a simple way to do this so I just render the currency symbol and then call the normal drawing function?

Comment: Can you show how you are populating that `DataGridView`, what you could do is find the longest length and pad the others with spaces and then change the alignment of the `DataGridViewCellStyle`...

Comment: Padding with spaces is one solution, but it will only work if you have a fixed-width font...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom numeric format string, which consists of one or more custom numeric specifiers, to define how to format numeric data. 
See Custom numeric format strings at url:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: *and* how does this solution address `currency symbols to line up on the left of cells`? Basically, how to *only* show the currency symbol on the left?

Comment: I believe this could be the basis on which to customize your formatting :

dataGridView1.Columns("Cost").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00"
dataGridView1.Columns("Cost").DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight
dataGridView1.Columns("Cost").DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 16, 0)